# list-box load items then save the file path of selected item

Tags: c#

Ok, so I have made some code here 
which will list all the directories and what I want to do is to display the folder names but when selected and push save it saves the file path not just the name

codes

the file look folder

```
FolderBrowserDialog elfenliedtopfan5wins = new FolderBrowserDialog();
       // elfenliedtopfan5wins.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles;
        if (elfenliedtopfan5wins.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // test 1 
            // Example #1: Write an array of strings to a file. 
            // Create a string array that consists of three lines. //raw = 0  \\raw\\images = 1 \\raw\\weapons = 2 \\raw\\weapons = 3 \\raw\\xmodel = 4 \\raw\\xmodelparts = 5 \\raw\\xmodelsurfs = 6
            string[] lines = { elfenliedtopfan5wins.SelectedPath + "\\raw" };
            // and then closes the file.
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\elfenlied_weapons\\path.txt", lines);
            string rawsave = elfenliedtopfan5wins.SelectedPath;
            Properties.Settings.Default.rawpath = rawsave;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            listbox();
            copyfilealais();



public void listbox()
    {
        LOADMOD.Items.Clear();
        string[] getfiles = Directory.GetFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.rawpath + "\\mods");
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Properties.Settings.Default.rawpath + "\\mods");

        foreach(string file in getfiles)
        {
            LOADMOD.Items.Add(file);
        }
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            LOADMOD.Items.Add(dir);
        }
    }
```

this way it works file but I don't want to show the path in the listbox. I just want the name of the folders which I added.

```
foreach(string file in getfiles)
        {
            LOADMOD.Items.Add(path.getfilename(file));
        }
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            LOADMOD.Items.Add(path.getfilename(dir));
        }
```

Which shows like this which is what I want but when I push save it just saves name of the folder aka this

so I was wording is their a way to have it like this picture with all folder names shown but when I push save it saves the file path not just the name?

[image of what i want it to be like but to save the path instead of the folder name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjyhD.png)

the save button

```
private void buttonX7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Properties.Settings.Default.modpath = LOADMOD.SelectedItem.ToString();
        // testing to see if it saves file path
        MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.modpath);

        richTextBoxEx1.LoadFile(Properties.Settings.Default.modpath + "//mod.csv", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
```

and I still want it to save the path but only way it does that if i don't include path.getfilename

does anyone have any-idea how i would be able to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keep `File name` or `File path` in each `Listbox` item, you can keep an `object` in it, then play with `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the `ListBox`.

In this scenario you need define just one simple class for your all `Listbox items` and create an instance of it for each item. In the following sample this class is `MyType`.

Inside MyType.cs file:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Path {get; set;}
}
```

Inside your main class:

```
public void listbox()
{
    LOADMOD.Items.Clear();
    string[] getfiles = Directory.GetFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.rawpath + "\\mods");
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Properties.Settings.Default.rawpath + "\\mods");

    LOADMOD.DisplayMember = "Name";
    LOADMOD.ValueMember = "Path";

    foreach(string file in getfiles)
    {
        // Create an item for the list
        var thisItem = new MyType {
            Name = path.getfilename(file),
            Path = file
            }; 

        LOADMOD.Items.Add(thisItem);
    }
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        // Create an item for the list
        var thisItem = new MyType {
            Name = path.getfilename(dir),
            Path = dir
            }; 

        LOADMOD.Items.Add(thisItem);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it with `Text` and `SelectedValue` properties of the `ListBox`. When you select an item you can write some codes like these:

```
string MyName = LOADMOD.Text; 
string MyPath = LOADMOD.SelectedValue;

// Now You have both Name and Path of your file or directory here
MessageBox.Show(MyName);
MessageBox.Show(MyPath);
```

Comment: ok umm thats confused me a little im still new to this so classes are still quite a big thing for me like adding things like listbox and stuff into a class confuses me quite a lot sorry to be a pain

Comment: No problem, i changed my codes in my answer to help you more... you need just create a simple class in project and put my codes in it. then change your listbox method in your codes and use it like above